# Syntax of complex numbers

Tags: math, equation

In inductive reactance equation \$X_L = j2\pi fL\$, why do we write "j" in front of "2πfL"? Does it matter where we put it? Could you show me example where denoting real and imaginary number makes equation clearer to read?

Comment: not even sure what you're asking here: of course multiplication is commutative, and you could put the \$j\$ wherever you'd like, but it's kind of the most important thing about that number that it's purely imaginary, and also, putting the imaginary unit somewhere in the middle would make understanding the magnitude of the imaginary part unnecessarily hard. It's a sensible convention to put it up front.

Comment: *Could you show me example where denoting real and imaginary number makes equation clearer to read?* Um, what? Every equation involving complex numbers, maybe? I think your confusion might stem from the fact that you're very early in your studies of complex currents and complex-valued impedances, and I *swear* that as soon as you actually start using this stuff to describe dynamic systems it'll become very natural and helpful, and you wouldn't want to go back to describing currents as DC and superimposed trigonometric functions.

Comment: As an aside, the **reactance** \$X\$ is a real value so there should not be a j or i. What you show is the **impedance** \$Z\$, which is a complex value.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about complex calculus. Best suited to a Math site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason you have to put it at the beginning (\$a+jb\$), for example placing it at the end (\$a + bj\$) is how the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) on complex numbers writes them.

What I wouldn't do is put them somewhere in the middle - for example \$2\pi fjL\$ is not exactly clear - you could easily miss a \$j\$ if you have lots of terms.

Writing the \$j\$ term first can be clearer, because it quickly allows you to identify which terms are imaginary and which are real. Just as a thought experiment, which one of these is easier to read?

$$r\cos(\theta)+jr\sin(\theta)$$
$$r\cos(\theta)+rj\sin(\theta)$$
$$r\cos(\theta)+r\sin(\theta)j$$